# Rest template.exchange returns response as junk while doing a GET request to a server running REST service in dot net core

Tags: java, resttemplate

}

Even i have setted the stringHttpMessageConverter to charset utf-8 but didnt work.

My code like

```
//restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-32")));
         HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverter = new ArrayList();
            httpMessageConverter.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverter);

        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(/*new URI(*/targetUrl/*)*/, httpMethod, reqEntity, String.class);
```

If you look at the response, it looks like an chinese chars..

Comment: What happens when you don't configure any converter? What is actually printed (post it!)? What is printed when you use your browser or a rest client to access the same URL (post the output!)? What is **supposed** to be returned by this service (post the expected output, content type and encoding)

Comment: In chrome browser/postman i am able to see the response json, since the repsonse type is json.  But in my code when i debug gives me string like   嬀笀∀椀搀∀㨀㄀Ⰰ∀渀愀洀攀∀㨀∀䌀䐀吀攀猀琀㈀㠀开㈀∀Ⰰ∀昀漀爀洀愀琀∀㨀∀攀匀䰀㄀　∀Ⰰ∀搀攀瘀椀挀攀∀㨀∀　㄀∀Ⰰ∀氀愀礀攀爀∀㨀∀　㄀∀Ⰰ∀琀漀漀氀一愀洀攀∀㨀∀䐀攀昀愀甀氀琀嘀愀氀甀攀∀Ⰰ∀挀爀攀愀琀攀搀吀椀洀攀∀㨀∀㈀　㄀㤀ⴀ　㘀ⴀ㈀㄀吀㄀㠀㨀㈀㘀㨀㌀㤀∀Ⰰ∀洀漀搀椀昀椀攀搀吀䤀洀攀∀㨀∀㈀　㄀㤀ⴀ　㠀ⴀ　㤀 　㄀㨀㐀㄀㨀㈀㄀∀Ⰰ∀氀漀挀愀琀椀漀渀∀㨀∀䐀㨀尀尀䐀愀琀愀尀尀刀攀猀甀氀琀猀㌀　　尀尀䌀䐀吀攀猀琀㈀㠀开㈀∀Ⰰ∀爀攀

Comment: Please read my comment again. Then edit your question, as requested. And answer the question in my comment, too: What happens when you don't configure any converter?

Comment: It gives me the same junk response with or without the converters.   My application has to consume the json response from another rest serivce written on dotnet core. When you use the url of that another service in any browser or postman, it gives response as json and diplayed in view.  Pronlem happens when i try to GET the data through my service, it returns some junky strings

Comment: I've had same problem and this worked for me as Marcelo B said in the comments below: new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8")

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your headers

```
httpHeaders.set("Accept-Charset", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(/*new URI(*/targetUrl/*)*/, httpMethod, reqEntity, Object.class);
```

Instead of String.class When i used Object.class then its start working for me.